# preg_match with exclusion

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm running into an issue with the following.

I need to clean up HTML before rendering it to the browser.

The current regex matches everthing like "{varname}" no problems so far, however I need to exclude matches which are found within script tags.

**Example was a bit unclear, so updated **
Example:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
this is an example `{var}` variable, <- this should be matched/removed
    <script>
    // don't match below arguments in other words don't let regex remove them/match them
    myMethod("{param1:'foo', param2:'bar'}");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here, but it sounds like you're parsing HTML with regex. [Don't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454). Use an HTML parser.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I'm a little confused here.

Comment: Hi Macek, I'm not parsing html with regex, i'm cleanup up.. For your info, data is set by the parser of CodeIgniter, ( CI uses {} as params/vars) However i don't want {} in my output to the browser ( this happens when vars weren't defined ). So that's why i want to clean up, however i want to keep the brackets in the javascript ofcourse.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to treat the root cause (undefined variables) rather than the symptom?

Comment: What's your current code? And just a guess: making it more specific would already avert matching contents with spaces, colons, quotes.

Comment: @Mario i only have the match for the {} right now, which is pretty basic as in preg_replace("~{(.*?)}~i", "", $sContent);

Comment: just did mario.. but have to get used to stackoverflow.. tried to @ the preg_replace on a new line.. but enter posted immediate.. so that's why i've replied with an halve answer.

Comment: Excluding a section of html with regukar expressions is akin to matching a section of html. You'll run into a heap of trouble either way.

Comment: To those who close this - the question is obvious!!!    It was some of the responses that clouded the issue.  I see EXACTLY what he needs done...  its regular expressions dudes!  sheesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it specific and just match alphanumeric characters:

```
preg_replace("~\{(\w+)}~i", "", $sContent);
```

Would avoid the `{x: 'y'}` example problem already.

---

To exclude document parts with preg, use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback); list the undesired `(<script>.+?</script>)|...` as first alternative, then switch-handle in the callback.

Comment: tnxx.. I was so stupid focused on the excluding script issue i misssed something easy as matching only alphanumeric.. Tnxx!